# Google Home act/listen on own response

Tags: smart-home, google-home, google-assistant

Is there a way to make Google Home act/listen to its own response?

For example, if I ask: `if it is gonna rain tomorrow` ---> if the response will be `yes` i.e. positive ---> I will set next action example `set reminder to take an umbrella with me tomorrow` which will be triggered only when there is this exact answer.

Simply make Google Home listen on its own answers and if the answer will be something specific then automatically trigger the next command. There are tons of use cases for this, I wrote only one example.

Note: I know about IFTTT but I don't think it supports this with Google Assistant.

Comment: why should it listen to its own answer? ... it already knows the answer

Comment: This is more like GH routine, but the routine will continue only if GH response to the routine step will match the criteria.

Comment: If might be easier forget Google home in this case, and use [if this, then that](https://ifttt.com/)